# Joint distribution of running max and min of a standard Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$, $M_t$, and $m_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and its running maximum and minimum, respectively. The joint distribution $(B_t, M_t)$, and hence by symmetry $(B_t, m_t)$, is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391196/joint-distribution-of-brownian-motion-and-its-running-maximum). Is there an equally easy closed form for the CDF of $(M_t, m_t)$?

Comment: Yes, the joint distribution of $(B_t,M_t,m_t)$ is known... you can find the result for instance in the Brownian motion book by Schilling & Partzsch ("Lévy's triple law").